# Using consistent RNG with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

So I have a function, let's call it `dostuff()` in which it's beneficial for my application to sometimes parallelize within, or to do it multiple times and parallelize the whole thing.  The function does not change though between both use cases.

Note: `object` is large enough that it cannot viably be stored in a list, and so it must be discarded with each iteration.

So, let's say our code looks like this:

```
bool parallelize_within = argv[1];
if (parallelize_within) {
    // here we assume parallelization is handled within the function dostuff()
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object randomized = function_that_accesses_rand();
        dostuff(i, randomized, parallelize_within);
    }
} else {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object randomized = function_that_accesses_rand();
        dostuff(i, randomized, parallelize_within);
    }
}
```

Obviously, we run into the issue that `dostuff()` will have threads access the random object at different times in different iterations of the same program.  This is not the case when `parallelize_within == true`, but when we run `dostuff()` in parallel individually per thread, is there a way to guarantee that the random object is accessed in order based on the iteration?  I know that I could do:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
```

which will guarantee that eventually, as iterations are assigned to threads at runtime dynamically, the objects will access rand in order with the iteration number, but for the first set of iterations it will be totally random.  Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: It seems a bit like an X/Y problem. "beneficial for my application to sometimes parallelize within, or to do it multiple times and parallelize the whole thing." Specifically this seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: The reason that it is circumstantially beneficial to parallelize in different ways, is that sometimes we only know how many times to call it based on a variable that gets updated each time it is called.  The user could decide that we know *a priori* how many times to call `dostuff()`.  Whether we call it adaptively or a fixed number of times is something the user chooses, but parallelizing within `dostuff()` is overall less efficient than assigning each thread to a call.  We choose the more efficient option when we can in our implementation.

Comment: could you pass i to function_that_accesses_rand(); and feed rng seed off it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all you have to make sure that both `function_that_accesses_rand` and `do_stuff` are threadsafe.
2. You do not have to duplicate your code if you use the `if` clause:
   `#pragma omp parallel for if(!parallelize_within)`
3. To make sure that in function `dostuff(i, randomized,...);` `i` reflects the order of creation of `randomized` object you have to do something like this:

```
int j = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for if(!parallelize_within)
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    int k;
    object randomized;
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        k = j++;
        randomized = function_that_accesses_rand();        
    }
    dostuff(k, randomized, parallelize_within);
}
```

4. You may eliminate the use of the `critical` section if your `function_that_accesses_rand` makes it possible, but I cannot be more specific without knowing your function. One solution is that this function returns the value representing the order. Do not forget that this function has to be threadsafe!

```
#pragma omp parallel for if(!parallelize_within)
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    int k;
    object randomized = function_that_accesses_rand(k);        
    dostuff(k, randomized, parallelize_within);
}

... function_that_accesses_rand(int& k){
 ...  
 #pragma omp atomic capture
 k = some_internal_counter++;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pre generate the random object and store it in a list. Then have a variable in the omp loop, that is incremented per thread.

```
// generate random objects
i=0
#pragma omp parallel for
for( ... ){
  do_stuff(...,rand_obj[i],...)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the wasted time, I should have specified: this random object cannot be stored in a list (as I initially attempted) because the list becomes a very expensive object RAM-wise when `i` is large.

Comment: You can store a function that will call it in the list though, and generate the correct one in the loop

Comment: Hmm.  Could you elaborate on this a bit?